# Check if program was started through windows autostart or manually

Tags: vb.net, windows, winforms, autostart

I am creating a windows forms application where the user can change if it should start on the startup of Windows.
This is done by creating a registry key.
Now i also want to add an option to start the program minimized, when it was automatically started.
How would i archive something like this?

Comment: Make the registry key pass a parameter to your application, e.g. `-minimized`, then check if that exists to determine if it should be minimized or not.

Comment: Notes that the start command in auto-start itself can have a qualifier to make the started program minimized. This would remove the need to code it inside the program.

Comment: @Aganju : I don't think those defined as registry keys have that option.